# How to set properly an object attribute using reflection in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

**Database ResultSet example**

```
fclass,geometry,scenario
""elementary_school"","MULTIPOINT(303400.907447057 9044592.97070337)",66
""elementary_school"","MULTIPOINT(302777.056751395 9044333.43169871)",66
""elementary_school"","MULTIPOINT(304182.88271353 9042435.93276122)",66
""elementary_school"","MULTIPOINT(304592.928219703 9041564.59729198)",66
""elementary_school"","MULTIPOINT(311385.417245523 9052785.71100888)",66
""worship"","MULTIPOINT(307397.04764638 9039421.31774996)",66
""worship"","MULTIPOINT(304384.660908793 9047145.34109501)",66
""worship"","MULTIPOINT(304518.616783947 9039859.48619132)",66
""worship"","MULTIPOINT(304689.11878157 9041491.61685193)",66
""worship"","MULTIPOINT(304711.539434326 9047763.53595371)",66
""worship"","MULTIPOINT(303420.353637529 9048419.36252138)",66
```

**Class to be accessed using reflection**

```java
public class Amenities {
    public Integer amenities_id;
    public Integer scenario;
    public String fclass;
    public String location;
    public String buffer;
    public TableInfo[] amenity_info;
}
```

**Using reflection**

```java
private PostStatus getAmenities(String layerUP, String layer, String[] tableUP, String[] table, String scenarioId) {
        PostStatus postStatus=new PostStatus();
        String values = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < tableUP.length; i++) {
            if (tableUP[i].equals("location")) {
                //values += "st_astext("+table[i]+")";
                values += "st_astext("+table[i]+") as "+table[i];
            } else if (tableUP[i].equals("scenario")) {
                values += scenarioId+" as scenario";
            } else {
                values = "property_json->'" + table[i] + "' as "+ table[i] ;
            }
            if (i < tableUP.length - 1) {
                values += ",";
            } else {
                values = values.replaceAll(",$", "");
            }
        }
        String errorMsg = "";
        String query ="";
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        upURL,
                        upUser,
                        upPassword)) {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            query="select " + values + " from user_layer\n"
                    + "inner join user_layer_data on user_layer.id = user_layer_data.user_layer_id\n"
                    + "where user_layer.id=" + layer;
            ResultSet data = statement.executeQuery(query);

            ArrayList<Amenities> data_in = new ArrayList<>();

            while (data.next()) {
                Object o = new Amenities();
                Class<?> c = o.getClass();
                for (int i = 0; i < tableUP.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        Field f = c.getDeclaredField(tableUP[i]);
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        if (!tableUP[i].equals("scenario") || !tableUP[i].equals("amenities_id")) {
                            f.set(o, data.getString(table[i]));
                        } else if (tableUP[i].equals("scenario")) {
                            Integer scen=(Integer)data.getInt(tableUP[i]);
                            f.set(o,scen );                            
                        } else if (tableUP[i].equals("location")) {
                            f.set(o, data.getString(table[i]));
                        } else if (tableUP[i].equals("amenities_id")) {
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | SQLException e) {
                        log.error(e, errorMsg);
                    }
                }
                log.debug(o, "reflection");
                data_in.add((Amenities) o);
            }
            Tables<Amenities> final_data = new Tables<Amenities>(data_in);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            postStatus=restTemplate.postForObject("http://" + upwsHost + ":" + upwsPort + "/amenities/", final_data, PostStatus.class);
            return postStatus;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            for (Throwable e : ex) {
                if (e instanceof SQLException) {

                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    errorMsg += "SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState();

                    errorMsg += "Error Code: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode();

                    errorMsg += "Message: " + e.getMessage();

                    /*Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                    while (t != null) {
                        errorMsg += "Cause: " + t;
                        t = t.getCause();
                    }*/
                }
            }
            log.error(ex, errorMsg+query);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e, errorMsg+query);
        }
        postStatus.status="Error";
        postStatus.message=errorMsg+query;
        return postStatus;
    }
```

My code is failing when it sets the value of the integer attribute of the object Amenites using the code `Integer scen=(Integer)data.getInt(tableUP[i]); f.set(o,scen );`, when I check the results the other values are assigned properly but the value of the field scenario remains in null.

I am sure that the values from the database ResultSet exist, also I tryied setting a static integer value `66`, and It only shows the field with a `0`value.

Since I am pretty new on Java, I would appreciate you help to find what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] - most of your variables are not defined in the code you showed.

Comment: Agree with @assylias. I'll also caution that this approach is likely to prove extremely fragile and error-prone as your table schema evolves. Consider using something like Spring JDBC and it's [RowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) interface (and not using reflection at all).

Comment: @Miguel What is `tableUP`? When you say "my code is failing", does it mean you are getting an exception? What is the exception? etc.

Comment: I updated the code and added the whole function. I agree this is my first approach, I will implement a better database managment in future iterations.

By failing I mean that I don't get the desired result, because the scenario value is not assigned.

Comment: @Miguel Have you used a debugger to run your code step by step and inspect variables to find the problem? For example I suspect that `if (!tableUP[i].equals("scenario") || !tableUP[i].equals("amenities_id"))` is always true and only the first branch of your if/else statement is run.

Comment: Yeah I would hate to be the developer that later on has to maintain this.... using Reflection should be the last resort... There are plenty of ORM tools out there that work very well (Hibernate for example)

Comment: @assylias thank you very much, your answer solved my issue. As you pointed my logic was wrong the correct one is if (!tableUP[i].equals("scenario") && !tableUP[i].equals("amenities_id"))